# Why do some users have a flyout appear when you hover over their names

Tags: support, user-accounts, user-profile-page

Just curious. Why do some users have a flyout appear when you hover over their names. It is quite nice.
Can this be enabled for any user or is it a reputation based thing?

Comment: [How do people see an expanded usercard?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need

1. at least 1000 rep
2. a non-empty “About me” box.

More info: [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user